Google Analytics GA4 - Dimensions that count for the 25 parameters limit per event
So we have reached the limit of the 25 parameters per event (which we had not noticed existed), and we are in the process of optimizing our tagging plan.
If there any clear info regarding if native dimensions do not count for that limit?
According to that site, https://www.rootandbranchgroup.com/ga4-event-parameters/, the 5 default automatic dimensions do not count: language, page_location, page_title, page_referer, screen_resolution.
Is that also the case when you explicitly send them with your event? (we use the JS api to send events, and override page_location and page_title with specific values)
And what about those native dimensions?

items
send_to
transaction_id
value
currency


the 25 event parameters limit applies to eps. Look at your ga4 network request. see the params that start with ep.? That's limited. Built-in params aren't counted towards the limit. You can look at them here on SO. SO has a few eps too.

@BNazaruk, thks, that helps. Just to confirm before adding an official answer (unless you want to add it):
the currency does not count then? (sent with cu=EUR for example)

no, the dimensions you've listed are some of the built-in dims and there are quite a lot of them really. It would really defeat the purpose  to count them in with the limitation given how many custom dims we had in UA. GA4 is quite a downgrade in comparison with UA, but Google really tries hard to conceal that fact and pretend this upgrade wasn't just a big cost mitigation effort. Well, they certainly lost a lot of paying customers to Adobe, Amplitude and even to Piwik and whatnot... Mixpanel, heh. I don't want to post an answer in case someone else has more substance to add. But feel free to.

:/ yes.
Well, value and transaction_id are sent with ep params (epn for value which is a metric), so I assume they count?
Checking in details I also see that debug_mode is part of ep params (less of a problem as it's only for test but still, it might impact our test properties if it counts)

I think you can just test it and write your findings. I think the epns count. Not sure about the debug mode. Didn't realize it was an ep. Does it pop as a dimension in GA4? Or is it just to display it in the debug view?

Yes. also thought I needed to test myself :)
So yesterday I sent an event:

33 params sent with my purchase event
minus 3 that were not received in GA4
minus 3 that we are pretty confident do not count: items, page_location, page_title
minus 2 that I'am pretty confident do no count: send_to, currency
-> give you 25 !!

I'll do another test with my code that reduces the amount to 25 when we exceed and re-check tomorrow if we get everything.
If conclusive I'll write an answer that may help others.

That's very nice of you. You probably shouldn't have to wait to test. The debugview in GA4 is real time and it should show all the eps you set and it should not show the ones that will be cut off.

I have a hard time trusting the debugView given all the bugs I've seen there since implementing GA4 ;) (when it works)

After some tests, here are my findings.
My confidence factor is around 90% that this is correct.
Thanks to @BNazaruk for the help in the comments.
The following parameters do not count against the 25 limit:

language
page_location
page_title
page_referer
screen_resolution
items
send_to
currency

The native parameters transaction_id and value do count.
